# How can I obtain the absolute settings of some Grid options?

Tags: options

For example:

```
Grid[{{10!}, {5!}}, ItemSize -> Full, Frame -> All]
```

What's the real value of `Full`?

How can I map the `Full` to a 2-d array? `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... }, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... }}`

Similarly there are some other values like `{Scaled[.3]}, Automatic`, If I can get the absolute values, then I can map them to the corresponding values in HTML files for example, weight height. Sometimes after rasterizing something to pictures, we can get the dimensions of the images. The tricky here is after exporting `Grid` content to HTML files(render as text), the `ItemSize` information is lost?

One background:

[my old question about ItemSize output in HTML files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25582/how-to-keep-itemsize-effect-when-export-to-html) (Is there any other easy ways?)

I've wrote one mapping function, [This is the effect web page](http://quaternions.blog.163.com/blog/static/2060821472013421113648650/), however I cannot find the NB files after one time I re-installed OS...

so...I need re-think the problem.

Comment: from help, it says on Full: `allow every item its full width and height`. So it depends on the item. i.e. it is computed during rendering, isn't? Only then the item size if fully known. What is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Nasser Similarly there are some other values like `{Scaled[.3]}, Automatic`, If I can get the absolute values, then I can map them to the corresponding values in HTML files for example, weight height.

Comment: I am not following you. But the way myself do these things is this: Do not use Full. I simply find the worst case needed for what I am doing, and fix the sizes so that it fits this worst case (i.e. I set ItemSize to that size that I determined). This way, nothing shifts and nothing changes positions during simulation or generating different output, since I have reserved on the screen all the area that I need. Again, I really not following what you are trying to do here. But may be someone will :)

Comment: @Nasser Fine, I'm trying to solve my linked question again, welcome some comments.

Comment: The only thing I can think to offer is to check the rasterized size of the objects, e.g. `Rasterize[10!, "RasterSize"]` -- is this of any use to you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Rasterize`? hmm? I'm trying render the Grid as text as one text table.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I thouht about this but it has to be improved, `Rasterize` breaks lines, try `Rasterize[100!, "RasterSize"]` and for `Full` item size there is no break. Also `ItemSize` has different units

Comment: @Mr.Wizard oh, I know what you mean, something like that.